# Create a Copy of a database in the same cluster - AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to copy the whole database (tables / views / function/ roles / grants & etc) into a new one in the same cluster for Dev-Prod use cases.
Let's say I have db name named "my_prod_db" - I would like to "copy paste" it into a new database named "my_dev_db".
I searched the web  an looks like the only option is using some system tables and automate the process somehow.
Anyone have an automated script or any other way of doing it ?
Thanks.

Comment: For DEV / TEST / Prod use cases, I would recommend you to take the snapshot of the cluster and then restore it into a Redshift Serverless endpoint. That way you can have the DEV/TEST environment ready, you pay only for the Redshift Manage storage and for compute in Redshift serverless you pay per usage.

Comment: Thanks, Added it to the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

For DEV / TEST / Prod use cases, I would recommend you to take the snapshot of the cluster and then restore it into a Redshift Serverless endpoint. That way you can have the DEV/TEST environment ready, you pay only for the Redshift Manage storage and for compute in Redshift serverless you pay per usage.